# Neyman-Pearson lemma. Doubt on the text of the lemma

Tags: probability, statistics

In my book:
$\mathbf{X}=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$
$f(\mathbf{x})$ is the joint density, where $f$ is either $f_0 \text{ or } f_1$.

Suppose we want to test $H_0: f=f_0$ or $H_1: f=f_1$. The test, whose test function is

$$\phi(\mathbf{X})=1\text{ if }\frac{f_1}{f_0}\geq k;$$

$$\phi(\mathbf{X})=0 \text{ otherwise,}$$

(for some $0<k<\infty$) is a most powerful test of $H_0$ versus $H_1$ at level $E_0(\phi(\mathbf{X}))$.

My question is how is $k$ defined? Can I interpret the lemma as if $\forall k \in (0,\infty)$ there will be a test function $\phi(\mathbf{X})$ such that it will determine the size for which the test with test function $\phi(\mathbf{X})$ is most powerful?

I'm just trying to understand which kind of relationship $k$ and the size of the test have between each other.

EDIT:

Here is a citation from the book I'm using: «the Neyman-Pearson lemma as stated here does not guarantee the existence of an MP $\alpha$ level test but merely states that the test that rejects $H_0$ for $T(X)\geq k$ will be an MP for some level $\alpha$» This makes me want to interpret as $\forall k \exists \alpha$. May I?

Comment: Please don't cross-post your questions here and on stats.stackexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your interpretation is correct. What the lemma is saying is that if you use the likelihood ratio **as** your test function (or something that is equivalent to it), then it *is* the most powerful test of the null vs. alt. hypothesis for a particular type I error rate. In particular, it has the highest power of all tests that have a significance level of $E_0(\phi(\mathbf{X}))$

The value $k$ defines the "rejection region" of the likelihood ratio test, and it determines the expected value of $\phi(\mathbf{X}): \phi(\mathbf{X})=1\text{ if }\frac{f_1}{f_0}\geq k; \;\;0 \;\;\text{otherwise}$

This is spelled out by the expression $E_0(\phi(\mathbf{X}))$ in the text; which says that the expected value of the test function un*der the null distribution* (i.e., that's why the subscript is $0$) is the level of the test. We can make this clearer by re-writting this as $E_0(\phi(\mathbf{X})|k)$ to make it clear that it depends on $k$. Now, $E_0(\phi(\mathbf{X})|k)=\alpha=$Type I error rate (as per Michael Hardy) in typical "hypothesis test" terminology.

The larger you make $k$, the smaller you  make  $E_0(\phi(\mathbf{X})|k)$ and hence you reduce your chances of rejecting the null when it is in fact true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If the size isn't given, can I choose any $k \in (0,\infty)$?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. For a given $f_0,f_1$, each value of $k$ determines a specific test "size" or type I error rate. if you don't care about the type I error rate, then why do any hypothesis test at all? Usually, you want to find $k:E_0(\phi(\mathbf{X})|k)\leq\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is your desired test size.

Comment: Here is a citation from the book «the Neyman-Pearson lemma as stated here does not guarantee the existence of an MP$\alpha$ level test but merely states that the test that rejects $H_0$ for $T(X)\geq k$ will be an MP for some level $\alpha$»
This makes me want to interpret as $\forall k \exists \alpha$. May I?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Your latter formulation is correct. Each $k$ can be associated with a most powerful test of level $\alpha$ for some $\alpha$

Answer (score 0):

One chooses $k$ usually by deciding how much probability of Type I error one will tolerate (i.e. falsely rejecting $H_0$), balanced against the power of the test, which is the probability of rejecting $H_0$ when $H_0$ is false.  And that is a subjecctive economic decision.

Comment: ,I thank you for your answer. 
Your answer seems to be from a more applied perspective. I was looking for an answer more based on the the text of the lemma itself. Could you help me in that way?